# How to convert a string such as "12|34|56|78" to and output of 12, 34, 56, 78 in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, string-parsing

i have to make a Convert constructor that takes a string. This string will hold the integers as a string of characters, numbers are separated by the character |. For example, if the parameter is the following string “12|34|56|78”, the resulting object will have the following values: 12, 34, 56, and 78.

```
for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    if(s[i]!='|')
        cout<<s[i]<<s[i+1]<<", ";

}
```

this is what ive done so far but the output i get is "12, |2, 34, |3.." how do i make it "12, 34, 56, 78" ?

Comment: See this program: https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/95lTim3PoX

Comment: @rsp thank you, worked and was super easy

Comment: i just want to clarify, the comma is not necessary, what i have to do it output the pair of numbers without the "|"

Comment: Your output doesn't fit to your code. You should get `12, 2|, 34, 4|, 56, 6|, `

Answer (score 2):

As-is you are printing out the `|` character even when the `if` condition is `true`. Using your approach modify the code to:

```
std::string s = "12|34|56|78";
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)  {
    if (s[i] == '|') {
        std::cout << ", ";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << s[i];
    }
}
```

If you want to modify the string itself then combine the [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [std::string::replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) functions as shown in [Shreevardhan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47391651/8202288).

Answer (score 2):

Simply do a find and replace all

```
std::string s("12|34|56|78");
for (auto f = s.find('|'); f != string::npos; f = s.find('|')) {
    s.replace(f, 1, ", ");
}
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

or, if you have a C-style string and just want the required output

```
char s[] = "12|34|56|78";

for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
    if (s[i] == '|') {
        cout << ", ";
    }
    else {
        cout << s[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the string with the '|'s to a string with ','s, you can try to use the function [replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) from std.

```
std::replace( s.begin(), s.end(), '|', ',');
```

Comment: I voted this up due to the approach, even thought the OP wanted a space after each comma too

Comment: The OP wants to replace `"|"` with `", "`. This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to create is a string split method:

```
//Split string -- reusable
vector<string> splitString(string str, string delimiter)
{
  vector<string>v;
  string token;
  size_t pos = 0;

  while((pos = str.find(delimiter)) != string::npos)
    {
      token = str.substr(0, pos);
      v.push_back(token);
      str.erase(0, str.find(delimiter) + delimiter.length());
    }
  v.push_back(str);
  return v;
}
```

So use the '|' as a delimiter and you'll get the following result :) !

Comment: This will however result in very ineffective code.

Comment: @Lundin Well, assuming the user wanted to just extract the integers....apart from that, why do you think it will be ineffective? Just curious.

Comment: You search through the same string over and over. You possibly resize a vector. You resize the string over and over. All the forced heap reallocations will murder any cache performance and also cause heap fragmentation. The resulting machine code will be horrible, thousands of times slower than a plain strtok() program in C. And no, the compiler can't magically optimize this code into the C equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If you just use the STL you don't have use a loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
int main() {
    std::string s = “12|34|56|78”;
    std::replace(s.begin(),s.end(),'|',',');
    std::cout << s << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Listen to Stephan T. Lavavej's STL lectures, if you have time. They are fun!
[Link](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-/C9-Lectures-Introduction-to-STL-with-Stephan-T-Lavavej)

Comment: This won't even compile.

Comment: now it will. somehow SO was not updating my edits.

Comment: The OP wants to replace `"|"` with `", "`. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Lundin No, the OP does not want that. Read his/her comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you just want a new string with the output you specified, you can do as simple as replacing the delimiter.(you can also copy new string and modify)

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string str="12|34|5|100";

 for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
 {
  if(str[i]=='|')
    str[i]=',';
 }

    cout<<str<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The idea of replacing the delimiter has already been covered by other answers, incuding not having to write the loop.

Comment: Also this doesn't add `", "` with a space.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/). It's a standard library function.

Citing the source:

`char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );`A sequence of calls to this function split str into tokens, which are sequences of contiguous characters separated by any of the characters that are part of delimiters.

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Isuka thanks, just edited the answer